# How can I fix a ValueError revert transaction on a sniper bot that reverts only when triggered by an event(PairCreated)..otherwise swap goes through?

Tags: solidity, ether, web3.py, python, brownie

```
    THIS IS A BOT TO SWAP ON UNISWAP WHEN NEW PAIR IS CREATED BUT WHEN BUY FUNCTION 
    IS TRIGGERED BY AN EVENT THE TRANSACTION REVERTS BUT BUY FUNCTION 
    GOES THROUGH WHEN TESTING JUST THE buy() FUNCTION

    **CODE**

    from web3 import Web3
    import asyncio
    from brownie import config, Contract, network, accounts
    import time
    from scripts.abi import uni_abi, uni_factory_abi


    provider = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["WEB3_INFURA_URL"]))
    uni_factory_contract = provider.eth.contract(
        address=config["networks"][network.show_active()]["uni_factory"], 
    abi=uni_factory_abi)
    uni_router = Contract.from_abi(
        "UniswapV2Router02", config["networks"][network.show_active()]["uni_router"], 
        uni_abi)


    time_until_revert = 180
    token_to_spend = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth"]
    token_to_buy = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["test_token"]
    amount_eth_to_spend = Web3.toWei(0.001, 'ether')


    def buy():
        account = get_account()
        nonce = get_account().nonce
        tx = uni_router.swapExactETHForTokens(
            0,
            [token_to_spend, token_to_buy],
            account,
            (int(time.time()) + time_until_revert), {
                'from': account,
                'value': amount_eth_to_spend,
                'gasPrice': Web3.toWei("100", "gwei"),
                'nonce': nonce
            })
        tx.wait(1)
        print(
            f"Snipe was succesfull, bought: {token_to_buy} using: {token_to_spend}... 
            {tx}")


    def get_account():
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


    def handle_event(event):
        print(Web3.toJSON(event))
        pair = Web3.toJSON(event)
        print(pair)
        token0 = str(Web3.toJSON(event['args']['token1']))
        token1 = str(Web3.toJSON(event['args']['token0']))
        print("Token0: " + token0)
        print("Token1: " + token1)
        if(token0.upper().strip('"') == token_to_spend.upper() and 
            token1.upper().strip('"') == token_to_buy.upper()):
            print("pair detected")
            buy()
        elif(token0.upper().strip('"') == token_to_buy.upper() and 
            token1.upper().strip('"') 
            == token_to_spend.upper()):
            print("pair detected")
            buy()
        else:
            print("next pair")


    async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
        while True:
            print("Looking for newly created pairs...")
            for PairCreated in event_filter.get_new_entries():
                handle_event(PairCreated)
            await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)


    def main():
        event_filter = uni_factory_contract.events.PairCreated.createFilter(
            fromBlock='latest')
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(
                asyncio.gather(
                    log_loop(event_filter, 2)))
        finally:
            loop.close()



    **CONSOLE:**

    Looking for newly created pairs...
    Looking for newly created pairs...
    {"args": {"token0": "0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab", "token1": 
    "0xCb0363e79135595B7859B761aAF90260b6B1F310", "pair": 
    "0x85E4D8e5619bFFB94944E11C920b670E99A7F62a", "": 41050}, "event": "PairCreated", 
    "logIndex": 26, "transactionIndex": 14, "transactionHash": 
    "0xc8d159e01485e60d2868b23add8af5514fdc8b51e46215e6c6e20dad5413e0c0", "address": 
    "0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f", "blockHash": 
    "0xc9de35aa10100f5d22b0e471aa6b4460eb53c742364264e40094eac6a066a274", 
    "blockNumber": 9982617}
    {"args": {"token0": "0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab", "token1": 
    "0xCb0363e79135595B7859B761aAF90260b6B1F310", "pair": 
    "0x85E4D8e5619bFFB94944E11C920b670E99A7F62a", "": 41050}, "event": "PairCreated", 
    "logIndex": 26, "transactionIndex": 14, "transactionHash": 
    "0xc8d159e01485e60d2868b23add8af5514fdc8b51e46215e6c6e20dad5413e0c0", "address": 
    "0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f", "blockHash": 
    "0xc9de35aa10100f5d22b0e471aa6b4460eb53c742364264e40094eac6a066a274", 
    "blockNumber": 9982617}
    Token0: "0xCb0363e79135595B7859B761aAF90260b6B1F310"
    Token1: "0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab"
    pair detected
    Transaction sent: 
            0x11b1fc2e05b32261f5b74549a8552e768c5254fd7f040ffffb1bae2328db8a3d
      Gas price: 1.00000001 gwei   Gas limit: 146845   Nonce: 452
      UniswapV2Router02.swapExactETHForTokens confirmed (reverted)   Block: 9982620   
            Gas used: 145777 (99.27%)

      File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
        return_value, frame = run(
      File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
        return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
      File "./scripts/sniper.py", line 76, in main
        loop.run_until_complete(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in 
            run_until_complete
        return future.result()
      File "./scripts/sniper.py", line 67, in log_loop
        handle_event(PairCreated)
      File "./scripts/sniper.py", line 58, in handle_event
        buy()
      File "./scripts/sniper.py", line 26, in buy
        tx = uni_router.swapExactETHForTokens(
      File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1629, in __call__
        return self.transact(*args)
      File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1502, in transact
        return tx["from"].transfer(
      File "brownie/network/account.py", line 682, in transfer
        receipt._raise_if_reverted(exc)
      File "brownie/network/transaction.py", line 428, in _raise_if_reverted
        raise exc or ValueError("Execution reverted")
    ValueError: Execution reverted
```

Comment: From the log it fails in a transaction after the pair is detected and before the "successful bought" message, so it likely fail at the buy function. You will have to analyze the transaction to determine why the contracts are causing an error.

Comment: Thanks for the response....what should I look for when analyzing the transaction?  Sorry I'm a noob....here's the tx hash... 0x11b1fc2e05b32261f5b74549a8552e768c5254fd7f040ffffb1bae2328db8a3d

Comment: Using tenderly https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/rinkeby/0x11b1fc2e05b32261f5b74549a8552e768c5254fd7f040ffffb1bae2328db8a3d/ or etherscan https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x11b1fc2e05b32261f5b74549a8552e768c5254fd7f040ffffb1bae2328db8a3d&type=gethtrace2 it run out of gas.

Comment: Hmm...strange....no matter what I do it keeps giving "out of gas" error.   But when I test only the buy function it goes through...only when it's triggered by the "PairCreated" event does it give an "out of gas" error....I've tried setting the gas to 1,000,000gwei and still said "out of gas" ...don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You can't set the gas to 1M gwei, it doesn't make sense, gas doesn't have unit. Currently the block gas limit is 30M in rinkeby. The error seems to be in one of the intervening tokens, since they don't have their source verified can't pinpoint the reason. There was recently a similar question, and it was caused by a bug in the token when amountOutMin was zero. Can you try a more reasonable value for  amountOutMin?

Comment: Hm.. I see what you mean about the gas....tried setting gasLimit, tried setting amountOutMin,....nothing....has something to do with buy() being triggered by "PairCreated"....can't figure it out though....

Comment: Ok so I've figured out that if the poll_interval is anything below 60 seconds the transaction will revert with the "out of gas" error.....do you know why?  It goes through fine if I set it to 60.  Is there anything I can do to use like a 5 second poll interval?

Comment: It is possible for a contract to revert if someone tries to buy tokens immediately after creation.